# SQL Query to display chronological data of multiple items

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I have a table as following:

```
Date, Security_Name, Price
1/1/00, AAPL, 100
1/1/00, BBRY, 200
...
1/2/00, AAPL, 101
1/2/00, BBRY, 195
...
```

I'm trying to write a query that displays this:

```
Date, Price_AAPL, Price_BBRY
1/1/00, 100, 200
1/2/00, 101, 195
```

I've tried this query ...

```
SELECT Date, Price
FROM Table
WHERE Security_Name = "AAPL" OR Security_Name = "BBRY"
```

But I got a result like the original stacked table. I'm thinking of duplicating another row somehow and it's beyond my ability.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: I thought this is a fairly simple problem. I have been looking at the W3 school SQL for an hour now without avail. I've tried a `SELECT Date, Price FROM Table WHERE Security_Name = "AAPL" OR Security_Name = "BBRY"` query except I got a result like the original stacked table. I'm thinking of duplicating another row somehow and it's beyond my ability.

Comment: You need to delete that comment and post your attempted solution in the question itself.

Comment: @dedalus_rex I added information from your comment to the question.  My hope is that change is enough to discourage more close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample data in Access 2007, the query below gives me this result set.  It differs from your requested output only in the column names.  If that's an issue, you could save my query and use it as the data source for another query where you alias the column names as desired.

```sql
Date      AAPL BBRY
1/1/2000   100  200
1/2/2000   101  195
```

And here's the SQL from my query.  If it works for you after you substitute your table name for *YourTable*, that's great.  However, you may find it useful to try creating your own similar query from scratch using Access' "Crosstab Query Wizard".  It's a helpful wizard.  :-)

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(y.Price) AS SumOfPrice
SELECT y.Date
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE (((y.Security_Name) In ("AAPL","BBRY")))
GROUP BY y.Date
PIVOT y.Security_Name;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm going to select it as the answer. If you don't mind can you explain what the queries are doing briefly? I have not gone beyond the `SELECT x, y FROM Table` so this is a bit beyond me. I'd like to learn this for future references

Comment: I think you're asking for an explanation of `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT`.  I really don't know how to explain those coherently.  Now that your problem has been solved, spend some time exploring in the query designer to study the effect of various changes.  That's the best way I know to understand `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH t2(dt) AS
(SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM t1)
SELECT
dt,
Price_AAPL = (SELECT price FROM t1 b WHERE b.dt = a.dt AND b.security_name = 'AAPL'),
Price_BBRY = (SELECT price FROM t1 c WHERE c.dt = a.dt AND c.security_name = 'BBRY')
FROM t2 a
```

without `WITH` clause

```
SELECT
dt,
Price_AAPL = (SELECT price FROM t1 b WHERE b.dt = a.dt AND b.security_name = 'AAPL'),
Price_BBRY = (SELECT price FROM t1 c WHERE c.dt = a.dt AND c.security_name = 'BBRY')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM t1) a
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this in Access and I'm getting: _Inalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'._ with the `WITH` highlighted.

Comment: @dedalus_rex, try the second one.